# Remove all zeros from a 2D String[][] array

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop

I have a String[][] array from which I want to create a new jagged array without null.

```
String[][] noZero = new String[WCCount][];
String spot = "0";
            for(int i = 0; i < WCCount; i++) {
                noZero[i] = new String[countArray[i]];
                for(int j = 0; j < countArray[i]; j++) {
                  if(!ny[i][j].equals(spot))
                    noZero[i][j] = String.valueOf(j+1);
                  else
                    continue;
                  }   
                }
```

The problem is that instead of only copying values to the noZero array when ny[i][j] is not equal to "0", it copies null to the noZero array when ny[i][j] is equal to "0".

It should just jump to the next iteration and not do anything if ny[i][j] is equal to "0".

Hope someone can help :-)

Comment: Did you even try anything?

Comment: Why are you using strings when your values are all numbers?

Comment: Maybe he's reading that from System.in or something and did not convert to numbers. if that is the case, nlk, you could use a Scanner to read and use nextDouble() to get your values.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example :

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
    if ("0".equals(array[i][j])) {
        // remove
        array[i][j] = null;
        // or
        // array[i][j]="";
    }
}}
```